# Complete reset windows 10 system-wide user keyboards

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, locale, localization

My Windows 10 system keyboards are messed up since I received this new laptop.  I mean there are 5 keyboards and only 2 are necessary.  Is there **any way to completely reset keyboards** into two only , ar-sa for Arabic and en-us for English ?? Is this possible through system registry or a system shell command ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

---

This example adds the Spanish language pack (“es-es") to the list of Windows display languages. To add other language packs, replace all instances of “es-es” with the language code of the desired language pack.

1. Install a language pack by using Lpksetup.exe or DISM.exe. To do
   this, open an elevated Command Prompt window, and run one of the
   following commands:

> ```
> dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\LanguagePack\es-es.cab
>
>
> lpksetup /i es-es /p C:\LanguagePacks\
> ```

2. Verify that the language pack is installed. To do this, type the
   following command at an elevated command prompt:

> dism /online /get-packages

[image: image 1]

Depending on the version of Windows 10, do one of the following:

**Windows 10, version 1903(build 18362) and later**: Change the Group Policy that governs the affected computer. Set the BlockCleanupOfUnusedPreinstalledLangPacks Group Policy Object (GPO) to Yes.

**Windows 10, versions 1803 and 1809**: Open a PowerShell window and run the following commands:

```
$A = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$A.Add("es-es")
Set-WinUserLanguageList $A -force
```

[image: image 2]

3. To verify that the language is now available, do one of the
   following:

In a PowerShell window, run

> Get-WinUserLanguageList

[image: image 3]

Select Settings > Time & Language > Language > Windows display language, and verify that Español (España) appears.